# Как определить и извлечь числа из ячеек с текстом?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть ячейки вида, например:

```
Ауди А7 - 6 шт.
```

И другая ячейка с ценой, допустим:

```
25
```

Задача такова, надо из 1-ой ячейки определить только число "6" и умножить его на количество из второй ячейки "25".

Разделители могут быть `-` или `—`.

Поиск, как я понимаю, наверное, должен происходить справа по ячейке. Если нет, то подскажите, как лучше.

Эта формула должна стоять в **третей ячейке** и выдавать числовой результат в ней.

С возможностью растягивать эту формулу по столбцу.

Comment: Без примера буде жесткова-то.

Comment: Ну вот человек очень хорошо отобразил то что требуется, ниже - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1090391/375100

Comment: Это я, а не человек.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное,

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(SPLIT(A1;"-—");1;2);"\d+") * B1
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Без примера сложно судить о качестве решения.

*Обновлено*

Судя по обсуждению в комментариях, следующий код также уместен

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[-—].*(\d+)") * B1
```

Чтобы не "страдать" от растягиваний, нужно использовать [ARRAYFORMULA](https://contributor.pw/post/google-sheets-formulas-arrayformula/)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A2,"[-—].*(\d+)") * B1:B2)
```

Comment: Да, решение очень подошло, это именно то!)) Главное что бы всегда правильно считало, а то перепроверять нереально вручную. Только можно добавить пожалуйста добавить что бы срабатывало и на "-" и на "—"?

Comment: И еще момент, в одной ячейке не сработало "Ауди 4 — 15 шт." (без А), то оно НЕ сработало. 

Пишет #VALUE (Ошибка Аргумент Параметр 1 в функции REGEXEXTRACT поддерживает только значения типа "текст". Тип значения "4" – число, поэтому его нельзя привести к типу "текст".

Тоесть оно почему то 15 пропустило вообще, и захотело 4.

Comment: @Константин, добавьте в свой вопрос пример с данными. Так работать нельзя. Хотите чтобы я гадал - наймите меня.

Comment: @Константин, буква `А` ни при чем, во втором примере другой символ перед количеством. Покажите примеры РАЗНЫХ данных. Количество может быть больше 99? В конце текста всегда есть три символа "шт."?

Comment: Вас понял. Спасибо большое, пример очень подошел для другого файла. А там где ошибка была, решил, что бы быстрее было упростить, вынес шт. просто в отдельный столбик, пусть так будет. Спасибо огромное за помощь!!

Comment: @Константин, обратите внимание, что я в `SPLIT` добавил еще один разделитель.

Comment: >> *вынес шт. просто в отдельный столбик, пусть так будет* - Вот так нужно делать всегда (по возможности).Даные любят порядок. А для показанных двух строк: `=B2*Left(Right(A2;6);3)`